# Android HttpPost get parameters

Tags: android, apache, http

I have the following code that i use to make a webcall. The server is returning an error below that indicates too many parameters. I send 20 params and there are 20 params in the webservice.

Is their a way of displaying the parameters that i send before i execute the post?

Thanks in advance.

```
try {
            // Add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID1", compID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID2", companyGuid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CompanyID", compID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TagID", tagID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ClientID", clientID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CarerID", carerID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneScanned", phoneScanned));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneSent",    phoneSent));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TXType", TXType));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneType", phoneType));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", latitude));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", longitude));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Driver", driver));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WiFiOn", wifiOn));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AndroidVersion", androidVersion));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RRVersion", rrVersion));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BatteryStrength", batteryStrength));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPSOn", gpsOn));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ManualButton", manualButton));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CarerSignedBackIn", carerSignedBackIn));



            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));



            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.e(TAG, "about to execute http post");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e(TAG, "just executed http post");
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.e(TAG, "responseBody  for RRPostTransactionNew = " + responseBody);



            DomParser dp = new DomParser(context);
            serviceStatus = dp.getPostTransactionResponseCode(responseBody);

            Log.e(TAG, "serviceStatus = " + serviceStatus);
```

.

```
Error: RRPostTransactionNew-Procedure or function RR2_PostTransactionNew has too many arguments specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy and see all requests and responces https://www.charlesproxy.com/